# What's the correct adverb to go with "renovated"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, adverbs

I've come across the following on billboards: "Newly renovated suites..."

It's apparent that the intended meaning here is "recently" and so I believe that "newly" may not be appropriate to go with "renovated", the reason being the definition of the verb "renovate", which is "to make new or as if new again"/"restore to good condition".

Comment: I'm sure you're technically correct but in real-estate speak "new" has particular power.

Comment: Could we say, there's a bit of redundancy here, when "newly" is used?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Recently+renovated%2Cnewly+renovated&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CRecently%20renovated%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnewly%20renovated%3B%2Cc0

Comment: *Newly renovated* is absolutely idiomatic in American English. Very few English speakers recognize that Latin "nov" is English "new".  English speakers would also tend to say "the *hoi polloi*".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based upon a false premise. Newly renovated is a perfectly accepted construction.

Comment: @ScotM: How do we explain the "accepted" redundancy there in that construction? Isn't it somewhat like, "I returned back to NY"? I'm eager to learn.

Comment: Confirming @TimRomano 's astute observation, the "redundancy" is lost in generations of expansion. In the housing and hospitality industries *renovation* simply means an extensive rehabilitation project. By the principle of depreciation, *newer* renovation work is more valuable and appealing to customers and clients than *older* renovation work.

Comment: Note that here *newly* means *recently*, not *made anew*. [See dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/newly). So there's no semantic redundancy, and since *new* and *nov-* don't sound that much alike, there's no phonetic redundancy. There's only etymological redundancy, which it is safe to completely ignore.

Comment: @Peter Shor: Thanks. That serves as the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible for a house or commercial building, built in 1920, say, to have been renovated in 1950. In the year 2015, the 1950s-era renovation might seem dated, and an English-speaker could easily say *I don't like the mid-century renovation. I'm looking for something renovated more recently* to which a real-estate agent might reply, "We do have a few *newly* renovated properties".

As I mentioned in my comment, very few English-speakers would recognize the word "new" in "re*nov*ation". Renovation simply means a freshening of appearance, usually cosmetic or decorative in nature, and usually not involving replacement of the electrical and plumbing systems or any major structural changes, although sometimes walls that do not bear loads may be removed, and smaller sections of old iron pipe may be replaced with modern solvent-welded PVC pipe, and electrical wiring might be brought up to current code.